# Error al convertir tipos de datos varchar a int

Tags: c#

```
string cmd = string.Format("EXEC GuardarUsuario '{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'", txtNom.Text.Trim(), txtApe.Text.Trim(), txtMail.Text.Trim(), txtUsu.Text.Trim(), txtPass.Text.Trim(), timeAlta.Text.Trim(), timeBaja.Text.Trim());
Utilidades.Ejecutar(cmd);
MessageBox.Show("se ha guardado correctamente");
return true;
```

Cuando ejecuto esa linea en mi Visual Studio me tira ese error que muestro en imagen, pero no sé dónde me equivoco porque creo que los convertí bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! estas pasando todos los datos como strings al usar ' entre ellos. seguramente alguno de ellos es un numero. el error esta en la llamada al SP.

Comment: Veo que le pusiste comillas simples a todos los campos, debe haber alguno que es entero y no las necesita, aún así MSSQL hace un casteo por lo que podría ser otra cosa, deberías compartir qué datos le mandas así como los campos de la tabla de qué tipos son para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: los primeros 5 campos que paso, son varchar y los ultimos dos serian datetime,  muchisimas gracias por las ayudas y correcciones

Comment: hay un dato que espera tipo int y le envias un varchar.
Al parecer conviertes todos a string antes.
Más codigo para entender mejor y ayudar más

Answer (score 0):

Ese error tiene pinta de que alguno de los parámetros que le estas pasando al procedimiento es un texto y el procedimiento te pide un entero, revisa los 6 parámetros que sean correctos:

"EXEC GuardarUsuario '{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}'"

Por otra parte si deseas evitar errores si estás utilizando C# 6 puedes construir el string de la siguiente forma:

$"EXEC GuardarUsuario '{txtNom.Text.Trim()}','{txtApe.Text.Trim()}','{txtMail.Text.Trim()}', '{txtUsu.Text.Trim()}','{txtPass.Text.Trim()},'{timeAlta.Text.Trim()}','{timeBaja.Text.Trim()}'"

Comment: excelente, se me fue el eerror ahi, pero ahora el problema es que no me quedo guardado en mi tabla de sqlserver

Comment: Hola, sino te quedó guardado seguramente será un error del procedimiento almacenado, puedes utilizar un try catch para intentar capturar el error ...